# Boost Spirit X3 and std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-x3

I want to parse into a `std::unordered_map`.

Example Code:

```
struct Base
{
  int item1;
  int item2;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Base, item1, item2)

namespace grammar
{
  using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

  auto base_ = rule<struct base_, Base>{"base"}
             = repeat(2)[ int_ ];

  auto start = rule<struct start, std::unordered_map<std::int32_t, Base>>{"start"}
             = (id_ >> base_) % eol;
}
```

With the following main:

```
namespace ios = boost::iostreams;
namespace fs  = boost::filesystem;
namespace x3  = boost::spirit::x3;

int main()
{
   std::unordered_map<std::int32_t, Base> bases;

   ios::mapped_file mmf("example.dat");

   auto beg = std::begin(mmf);
   auto end = std::end(mmf);

   auto ret = x3::phrase_parse(beg, end, grammar::start, x3::char_(','), bases);

   if (ret && beg == end)
   {
      std::cout << "Parse ok\n";
   }

   mmf.close();

   return 0;
}
```

and one example file:

```
1,2,3
2,3,4
3,4,5
```

The compiler error message is:

```
.... ‘class std::unordered_map<int, Base>’ has no member named ‘push_back’
```

What to do next, is there a way da adapt `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: You can inherit from unordered_map, and implement the push_back function.

Comment: [Boost 1.60](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5XpIcGasUhW6GYkN) vs [Boost 1.61](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/H2ud3MKyMTj1G747).

Comment: @jv_, Thanks, this worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likee jv_ supposed, updating my boost version fixed the problem.